# wget command not working in Bash script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

wget is working in terminal but when I write it in script it's not downloading full webpage.

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=breast+cancer+&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.PreviousPageName=results&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.SpecialPageName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetsUrlFrag=filters%3DNewspaperArticle%3BJournalArticle%3BHistoricalArticle%3Bffrft%3Bds1_2017%2F05%2F01_2018%2F04%2F31&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetSubmitted=false&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.BMFacets=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPresentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sSort=none&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FFormat=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FSort=&email_format=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.email_sort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.email_count=20&email_start=21&email_address=&email_subj=cancer+Filters%3A+Newspaper+Article%2C+Journal+Article+-+PubMed&email_add_text=&EmailCheck1=&EmailCheck2=&coll_start=21&citman_count=20&citman_start=21&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FileFormat=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastPresentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Presentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastPageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Sort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FileSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Format=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastFormat=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevPageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevPresentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevSort=&CollectionStartIndex=1&CitationManagerStartIndex=1&CitationManagerCustomRange=false&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_ResultsController.ResultCount=63604&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_ResultsController.RunLastQuery=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.cPage=10&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.CurrPage=10&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.cPage=2&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailReport=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailFormat=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailCount=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailStart=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Email=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailSubject=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailText=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailQueryKey=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailHID=1pMK_vh9yQRGCP_J3IDx5cepvi5cuzoWaprHdrtYod7om6l-aqvyufdeyo8hwkqEh8ns9uxWjg8qqoYxVJPtD2XqwckBzh9sas&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.QueryDescription=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Key=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Answer=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Holding=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.HoldingFft=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.HoldingNdiSet=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.OToolValue=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.SubjectList=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.TimelineAdPlaceHolder.CurrTimelineYear=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.TimelineAdPlaceHolder.BlobID=NCID_1_285500630_130.14.22.215_9001_1528096993_1064396231_0MetA0_S_MegaStore_F_1&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Db=pubmed&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastDb=pubmed&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Term=cancer&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastTabCmd=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastQueryKey=1&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.IdsFromResult=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastIdsFromResult=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkReadableName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkSrcDb=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Cmd=PageChanged&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.TabCmd=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.QueryKey=&p%24a=EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.cPage&p%24l=EntrezSystem2&p%24st=pubmed";

wget $URL
wait
```

```
The name is too long, 5068 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is index.html?term=breast+cancer+&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.PreviousPageName=results&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.SpecialPageName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetsUrlFrag=filt.
--2018-06-04 16:46:00--  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=breast+cancer+&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.PreviousPageName=results&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.SpecialPageName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetsUrlFrag=filters%3DNewspaperArticle%3BJournalArticle%3BHistoricalArticle%3Bffrft%3Bds1_2017%2F05%2F01_2018%2F04%2F31&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetSubmitted=false&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.BMFacets=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPresentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sSort=none&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FFormat=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FSort=&email_format=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.email_sort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.email_count=20&email_start=21&email_address=&email_subj=cancer+Filters%3A+Newspaper+Article%2C+Journal+Article+-+PubMed&email_add_text=&EmailCheck1=&EmailCheck2=&coll_start=21&citman_count=20&citman_start=21&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FileFormat=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastPresentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Presentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastPageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Sort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FileSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Format=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastFormat=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevPageSize=20&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevPresentation=docsum&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevSort=&CollectionStartIndex=1&CitationManagerStartIndex=1&CitationManagerCustomRange=false&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_ResultsController.ResultCount=63604&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_ResultsController.RunLastQuery=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.cPage=10&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.CurrPage=10&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.cPage=2&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailReport=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailFormat=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailCount=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailStart=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailSort=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Email=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailSubject=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailText=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailQueryKey=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailHID=1pMK_vh9yQRGCP_J3IDx5cepvi5cuzoWaprHdrtYod7om6l-aqvyufdeyo8hwkqEh8ns9uxWjg8qqoYxVJPtD2XqwckBzh9sas&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.QueryDescription=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Key=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Answer=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Holding=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.HoldingFft=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.HoldingNdiSet=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.OToolValue=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.SubjectList=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.TimelineAdPlaceHolder.CurrTimelineYear=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.TimelineAdPlaceHolder.BlobID=NCID_1_285500630_130.14.22.215_9001_1528096993_1064396231_0MetA0_S_MegaStore_F_1&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Db=pubmed&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastDb=pubmed&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Term=cancer&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastTabCmd=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastQueryKey=1&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.IdsFromResult=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastIdsFromResult=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkReadableName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkSrcDb=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Cmd=PageChanged&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.TabCmd=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.QueryKey=&p%24a=EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.cPage&p%24l=EntrezSystem2&p%24st=pubmed
Resolving www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)... 130.14.29.110, 2607:f220:41e:4290::110
Connecting to www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)|130.14.29.110|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html?term=breast+cancer+&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.PreviousPageName=results&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.SpecialPageName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetsUrlFrag=filt.2’

index.html?term=bre     [   <=>              ]  61.47K   144KB/s    in 0.4s    

2018-06-04 16:46:03 (144 KB/s) - ‘index.html?term=breast+cancer+&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.PreviousPageName=results&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.SpecialPageName=&EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetsUrlFrag=filt.2’ saved [62943]
```

Comment: what is the value you get when you echo $URL in the script

Comment: Quote your variables! And what’s the `wait` for?!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XFzbgXwV link of ourpu

Comment: [“The name is too long” when using Wget](https://superuser.com/q/790244/173513) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) and [Issue 40908, Wget checks URL name for length...](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?40908) in the Wget bug tracker.